# Error al querer guardar datos de formulario PHP a MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy guardando unos datos desde un formulario de php a mysql pero no se en donde estoy mal , pero no me guarda nada, este es el codigo que tengo en mi php

**MI HTML**

```
<form class="limpiar" method="POST">
  <div class="half izquierda limpiar">
    <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="Ingresa Titulo" >
    <input type="text" id="claves" name="claves" placeholder="Ingresar palabras claves" >
    <input type="text" id="siglas" name="siglas" placeholder="Ingresar siglas de institucion">
    <input type="text" id="fecha" name="fecha" placeholder="Ingresar año-mes-dia">
    <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" placeholder="Ingresar numero">
    <input type="text" id="categoria" name="categoria" placeholder="Ingresar categoria">
    <input type="text" id="rutapdf" name="pdf" placeholder="Ingresar ruta de PDF ">

  </div>

  <div class="half derecha limpiar">
    <input type="text" id="autores" name="autores" placeholder="Ingresar autores">
    <input type="text" id="institucion" name="institucion" placeholder="Ingresar Institucion">
    <input type="text" id="ruta" name="rutaphp" placeholder="Ingresar ruta de php">
    <input type="text" id="volumen" name="volumen" placeholder="Ingresar volumen">
    <textarea name="descripcion" type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Descripción"></textarea>
  </div>  
  <input type="submit" name="btn-guardar" id="input-submit">
</form>
```

y este es mi codigo para que lo guarde

**MI PHP**

```
<?php
include_once '../php/conexion.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-guardar']))
{
 // variables for input data
 $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
 $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
 $autores = $_POST['autores'];
 $pclaves = $_POST['claves'];
 $siglas = $_POST['siglas'];
 //$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
 $numero = $_POST['numero'];
 $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
 $pdf = $_POST['pdf'];
 $institucion = $_POST['institucion'];
 $rutaphp = $_POST['rutaphp'];
 $volumen = $_POST['volumen'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli($hostbd,$usuariobd,$clave,$basededatos);
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO articulos(Titulo,Descripcion,Autor,Institucion,Siglas_Institucion,Url,Keyword,Volumen,Numero,Categoria,Rutapdf) VALUES('$titulo','$descripcion','$autores','$institucion','$siglas','$rutaphp','$pclaves','$volumen','$numero','$categoria','$pdf')";

  if($resultado=$mysqli->query($sql_query))
 {
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  alert('Datos insertados');
  window.location.href='form.php';
  </script>
  <?php
 }
 else{?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  alert('Error al guardar');
  window.location.href='form.php';
  </script>
  <?php
 }
}
?>
```

Se que es un error porque el alert('Error al guardar siempre me aparece') que tengo arriba siempre me aparece y no me guarda nada

Comment: Hola, tienes algún log que puedas compartir? para conocer más sobre el error

Comment: Intenta hacer un __echo $sql_query;__ y correr la consulta que te devuelve para ver si está bien formulada

Comment: Imprime $resultado para ver el error y poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero te recomendaría que no mezcles el código `html` con el de `php`.

En segundo lugar estas metiendo `Strings` en todo los campos de la tabla y creo que no todos son del tipo `varchar` por lo que el error te puede venir de ahí.

Para meter las variables tienes que combinar el `String` de la `query` con las variables separandolas por comilla y concatenandolas con puntos.

Entonces quedaría algo así:

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO articulos(Titulo,Descripcion,Autor,Institucion,Siglas_Institucion,Url,Keyword,Volumen,Numero,Categoria,Rutapdf) VALUES('".$titulo."','".$descripcion."','".$autores."','".$institucion."','".$siglas."','".$rutaphp."','".$pclaves."','".$volumen."',".$numero.",'".$categoria."','".$pdf."')";
```

Esta solución puede que no sea buena del todo por que no se cuál de estos datos es númerico y cuál es de tipo varchar, Pero ten en cuenta que los varchar tienen que ir entre comillas `('".$variable."')` y los numéricos sin ellas `(".$variable.")`.